# TypeA and TypeB are alias to a same primary type, how can they be deduced as different type in C++ template?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, type-traits

I has two different aliased types pointing to a same primary type:

```c
using TypeA = unsigned long
using TypeB = unsigned long
```

and I am implementing type traits for them. My goal is to deduce different value for them.

```c
template <typename T>
struct LengthTrait {
    constexpr static int size = 5;
};

template<>
struct LengthTrait<TypeA> {
    constexpr  static int size = 4;
};

template<>
struct LengthTrait<TypeB> {
    constexpr  static int size = 8;
};
```

but compiler tell me TypeA and TypeB are all of type `unsigned long` so the code can't compile.

My question is:
Is there any way to treat TypeA and TypeB differently?

I tried using `typedef` instead of `using`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Aliases don't exist as far as the type system goes, they're both `unsigned long` and nothing else.

The closest thing that I know of is to make them enums:

```
enum TypeA : unsigned long {};
enum TypeB : unsigned long {};
```

That way they are unique types and can still be used as integers (with annoyances).

Comment: thank you for the info. Is there anything like a `alias trait` then?

Comment: What language is `alias trait` from? Traits in general are formalized as ["concepts"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) in C++20 . Traits are hacked into earlier versions with a technique called [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)

Comment: @DeanSinaean If by "alias trait", you mean "any capability to distinguish between two names that are both aliases for the same underlying type"  (e.g.  between `TypeA` and `TypeB` in your question), then there is no such thing as an alias trait in C++.

Comment: @Peter  I really hope there was such a thing.

Comment: @parktomatomi by saying `alias trait`, I mean some mechanism to distinguish aliases. It is not a terminology in use.