# c++ type aliases ambiguity when initializing fully specialized template

Tags: c++, alias, using, template-specialization, ambiguous

I am trying to initialize my template class with a type alias as template parameter, but only the specialized version of my class is created. I understand the problem is in the ambiguity of my aliases. Is there a workaround?

```
#include <iostream>

using Type1 = size_t;
using Type2 = size_t;

template <class Type>
class SomeClass {
public:
    void doSomething() {
    }
};

template <>
class SomeClass<Type1> {
public:
};

int main() {
    SomeClass<Type1> someClass1;    // SomeClass<Type1> is initialized

    SomeClass<Type2> someClass2;    // ... and also SomeClass<Type1> is initialized ???
    someClass2.doSomething();       // and therefor doSomething() is not working...
}
```

Comment: its not "ambiguity", `Type1` and `Type2` are identical types.

Comment: Type aliases are not strong types

Comment: what is the aim? What are you trying to achieve? Why do you think you need to distinguish between  `size_t` and `size_t` ?

Comment: Boost has a strong type alias `boost/strong_typedef`

Comment: Ok, i understand this. Is there a workaround me to achieve my goal?

Comment: what is your goal? This is a classical [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So far you only told us about your solution (that cannot work), what is missing is, the actual issue this is supposed to solve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeA and TypeB are alias to a same primary type, how can they be deduced as different type in C++ template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829346/typea-and-typeb-are-alias-to-a-same-primary-type-how-can-they-be-deduced-as-dif)

Comment: What do you think **alias** means?

Answer (score 3):

What you ask for is not possible. Not directly. Type aliases merely introduce a name that refers to the type. In your code `Type1` and `Type2` really are the same type.

What you can do: A level of indirection.

```
#include <iostream>


template <class Type>
class SomeClass {
public:
    void doSomething() {
    }
};


struct Type1 {
    using type = size_t;    
};
struct Type2 {
    using type = size_t;
};

template <>
class SomeClass<Type1> {
public:
};


int main() {
    SomeClass<Type1> someClass1;    

    SomeClass<Type2> someClass2;    
    someClass2.doSomething();       
}
```

And what before used `Type` in `SomeClass` now uses `typename Type::type`. Now `SomeClass<Type1>` and `SomeClass<Type2>` are two different instantiations, nevertheless they can use the same `type`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what i needed...

Comment: @MiroslavKrajcir The best "thank you" is to accept the answer.